# Match 1 or more free standing non unicode alpha numeric characters

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a single pattern to match, free-standing collections of non-Unicode alpha numeric characters. I will eventually do a replace with a single space.

**Prerequisite**

- In regard to *alpha* characters, the Unicode category `\p{L}` is necessary
- In regard to *numeric* `\d` is adequate
- white space is included

**Match Examples**

<sub>*'/' denotes **any** non-unicode alpha numeric character*</sub>

```
aàa 111 /
   ^   ^^
```

```
aàa / 111
   ^^^
```

```
aàa /// 111
   ^^^^^
```

```
aàa/// 111
   ^^^^
```

```
aàa ///111
   ^^^^
```

```
aàa *&^#* 111
   ^^^^^^^
```

```
)(*)* 111
^^^^^^
```

```
à- 1
 ^^
```

```
à -1
 ^^
```

**Unmatched Examples**

```
aàa///111
```

```
aàa-111
```

```
aà-/*&^*-a-1-1-1
```

**What I have so far**

- The pattern `[^\p{L}\d]` will match any non-alpha numeric pattern.
- Zero-width negative lookahead / lookbehind with word boundaries gets it closer e.g. `(?<!\b)[^\p{L}\d](?!\b)`

However, a pattern that solves all the above examples has been elusive

**Note**: my spidey senses tell me this is likely possible with a single pattern. Though, if this is more efficient or practical as 2 separate patterns, so be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\b` word boundaries are problematic because those match a boundary between `\w` and `\W`, but you're not using `\w` and `\W`.

It looks like you always want whitespace on one side or the other of a match so that needs to be worked in. Give this a try. It matches `[^\p{L}\d\n]*` either preceded or followed by `[ \t]+`.

```
[ \t]+[^\p{L}\d\n]*|[^\p{L}\d\n]*[ \t]+
```

Demo:

[image: Regex101.com demo]

Visual Representation

[image]

Comment: I added the visualizer just for fun, you can remove it if you like